# Dynamic row and column in table layout according to screen size Android

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am making my own minsweeper game.I am currently stuck at one position where I want to create table row and column in Table Layout run time according to screen size.Table rows and columns should fill the screen according to device screen size.

So basically I want to determine total number of rows and column in table layout according to screen size where column width is 24.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get display width by

```
Point p = new Point();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(p);
```

and get box size

```
int w = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.box_size);
```

Now you can figure number of columns by dividing display width to box width

```
int col = (int) Math.floor(p.x / w);
```

Comment: what is box_size?

Comment: @user2042979 It's your minsweeper size. you say it is 24

Comment: tried it is giving col=13 but that is exceeding my screen size

Comment: It is better to define the size in res as dp and read value like what I do above